# Configure WebLogic 12c Data Source

Tags: java, classpath, datasource, weblogic12c, netezza

I have the Generic installation of Oracle WebLogic Server 12.2.1.3 on my MacBook.

I am trying to setup a Netezza datasource and I am having an issue getting it to recognize the nzjdbc.jar I am trying to use.

Some installation paths:

```
WL_HOME="/Users/cpritcha/oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver"
DOMAIN_HOME="/Users/cpritcha/oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/wl_server"
```

I have my jar placed in `{WL_HOME}/server/lib`

But when I launch

```
{DOMAIN_HOME}/bin/startWebLogic.sh
```

and try to configure my datasource, it says

```
weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceSystemException: Cannot load driver class org.netezza.Driver for datasource 'gdwDS'
```

I have tried going to `startWebLogic.sh` and doing

```
SAVE_CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}:/Users/cpritcha/oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/nzjdbc.jar"
```

But that still had no effect. 
Is there something I am missing? How can I make WebLogic recognize and load this 3rd Party driver?

Answer (score 0):

try modifying: ${WL_HOME}/oracle_common/bin/commEnv.sh

and adding the same full path (and jar file) to WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH